# Custom php.ini file not working in VPS hosting

Tags: php, apache, vps

I've tried going through Network Solutions tech support but didn't get it resolved ("You need to talk to Signature Support, which is $50"). 
I'm running some sites off of a Net Sol VPS account and need to change the upload_max_filesize setting (which is apparently set to a paltry 2MB by default) for the php server. I've added:

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
max_execution_time = 6000
```

to the /httpdocs/cgi-bin/php.ini file (per NS's instructions), and then restarted apache, but when I run a phpinfo on that domain, the settings are not applied. It still says "2M" for the upload max.

I also tried adding this to the server root at /cgi-bin/php.ini as well, to no effect.

There is no /cgi-bin/.php/php.coalesced.ini file that I can see.

Any ideas? I'm losing my mind with this.

Answer (score 0):

First thought is to check your phpinfo() output for the value listed in the "Loaded Configuration File" setting and make sure that it matches the file you've been editing.

Comment: Indeed, I did notice that the loaded config file is "/etc/php.ini" but I don't seem to have access to that directory... At least, it doesn't show up in the Plesk file manager or in Coda. Because the NS site says to put your config file into the "cgi-bin" directory, I assume that is supposed to override the properties in the other file. Obviously not. :-(

Comment: Did you delete php.ini.coalesced? Maybe your FTP client is hiding the dot file. Can you see it with a shell? http://www.networksolutions.com/support/php-ini-for-unix-shared-hosting-faq/

Comment: Did not delete coalesced file; I've got Coda configured to show hidden files... Not sure if that means it should show hidden folders as well. I don't know how to connect via a shell yet... Thanks for the replies.

Comment: I have this exact same issue.  I have used Dreamweaver, Filezilla Cyberduck - result in same effects as you describe.  This is literally the exact same scenario as I am currently experiencing except one point - network solutions has raised the cost of server from $50 to $60 for help.  Has anyone solved this issue?  I also am new to command line so I dont know the commands to ssh into my system.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just litter PHP.ini files around and expect PHP to load them. If it's not been told to look for one in that cgi-bin directory, the file will just get ignored.

Check the `phpinfo()` output - the first section will tell you exactly what .ini files were located/parsed, and their location. e.g. on my home server:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php5/apache2
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/curl.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/gmp.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mysql.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mysqli.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/pdo.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini
```

if your cgi-bin .ini file isn't listed, then PHP is NOT looking in that directory.

Comment: Yep, you and Alex had the same feedback (I replied to his answer first by accident). Question is, how do I access the "/etc/php.ini" file instead, when it's not visible in the Plesk file manager or in my FTP client (with invisible items shown)?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but figured I'd share my experience. I tried adding a php.ini file to the /cgi-bin folder as I read was suggested, that didn't appear to work. My solution was to SSH onto the server and make a change to the real php.ini file and then restarting the server.